# How to change audio volume of a live video feed in AVPlayer?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, video-streaming, live-streaming

Im developing an application which has 3 live video feeds on screen at once. For this I'm using AVPlayer in the AVFoundation framework.

However, there is a requirement that the video should only output audio once it has been clicked on and selected. At the moment I have the video and audio all playing at the same time.

Hence, im trying to create a way to mute the audio on each AVPlayer.

Ive searched various threads for an answer for this but have failed to find out anything so far.

The closest i had come to creating this was to get the audio tracks in the feed via AVAssestTrack and change the volume via AVMutableAudioMix.

However, im getting back 0 items in my audio tracks array!

Please can someone take a look at my code and see where im making a mistake or if there is a better way of doing this?

Thanks for your help!

```
- (IBAction)touchVolumeButton:(id)sender {

float volume = 0.0f;

AVPlayerItem *currentItem = self.player.currentItem;
NSArray *audioTracks = [currentItem.asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];

NSMutableArray *allAudioParams = [NSMutableArray array];

for (AVAssetTrack *track in audioTracks) {
    AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters *audioInputParams =
    [AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters audioMixInputParameters];
    [audioInputParams setVolume:volume atTime:kCMTimeZero];
    [audioInputParams setTrackID:[track trackID]];
    [allAudioParams addObject:audioInputParams];
}

if ([allAudioParams count] > 0) {
    AVMutableAudioMix *audioMix = [AVMutableAudioMix audioMix];
    [audioMix setInputParameters:[NSArray arrayWithObject:allAudioParams]];
    [currentItem setAudioMix:audioMix];

    AVAssetExportSession *session = [AVAssetExportSession exportSessionWithAsset:currentItem.asset presetName:@"current"];
    session.audioMix = audioMix;
}
}
```

Comment: have you created different objects of all the 3 players you are using.

Comment: yes i have, all are using there own instances of my player object class.

Comment: Any help guys? Im using a HLS video stream for the video which has the audio embedded in! I found out from elsewhere that i need to embed two audio tracks to the stream. One with audio and one without audio. Hence, the streaming team has embedded this. However, using the code above - tracks are still coming back from the current player item as zero/empty! Im stumped!

Answer (score 0):

Note that, per Apple, you can only use `AVMutableAudioMix` to control volume in this way with *file*-based assets. This does not work with streaming media.

Please see the following tech note:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1716/_index.html

I have confirmed on iOS 11 that this doesn't work with streaming media, with the same result (returning an empty array of tracks).